# Cannot install windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, uefi, windows

First of all excuse me for not being experienced and please bear with me.

I was having a stable system of Ubuntu 18.04 alongside win 10 which I rarely use. After I made a clean Install of Ubuntu 20.04, I faced some problems in Ubuntu 20.04 and win 10 also wasn't working at all.

When I tried to reinstall Ubuntu I unfortunately got many small partitions that I had to delete them, and after that while reinstalling Ubuntu I was forced to make a EFI partition and disable legacy support from bios.

After that I couldn't repair win 10 and reformatted the partition and tried to make a clean install of it alongside Ubuntu 20.04, but the installation keeps restarting giving me the error of: Inaccessible boot device.

I can make a clean install of both but Please help me in booting Ubuntu alongside windows correctly.

Here is an image of the disk from gparted:

[image]

Comment: This question has been answered many times and there are lots of good guides. Google is you friend here. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot is the Ubuntu guide. There are plenty of videos on YouTube too

Comment: Clean the entire disk and first install windows on a partition and then try to install ubuntu on another. As you can't install (I mean dual boot) Windows if there is an os already installed but Ubuntu can be installed along with another os. And follow the link provided by PonJar.

Comment: @PonJar I've been searching for the last couple of days, but as I'm said I'm not very experienced so I'm not sure exactly what's wrong and I would appreciate helping me solving it.

Comment: @Injamul Mohammad Mollah I remember I've installed Ubuntu first when I prepared the disk for the first time and then installed win 10 later and everything was ok untill I deleted the Ubuntu partition and made a EFI one. Isn't there any solution that I can keep the other three partitions untouched?

Comment: A google search of “how to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10” will give you all the basic information you need. If your question is about how to sort out a particular scenario of partitions then we would need more information. Add a screenshot of a gparted window showing the drive in question. What ever you do you would be well advised to make a backup of the partitions you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you. I've added an image of gparted to the question above.

Comment: I cannot access the image.

Comment: @ Nathaniel Sturtz . sorry edited the link

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you might experience issues with the partitioning.

My best bet is to start from scratch, wipe the entire disk, install Windows while leaving an empty partition for Ubuntu during installation, then installing Ubuntu to that partition.

The details are all covered in the guide provided by PonJar https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot.

Comment: I would appreciate a solution that will allow me to keep the disk unformated as I have another three partitions with my data on them.

Comment: If you know what you're doing, you could probably use a tool like gparted to sort out the partition mess first, then install Windows to a specific partition, and then ubuntu to another specific partition. AFAIK both will allow you to specify the partition to install to.

Comment: I've edited the question to add an image for the disk from gparted. I just need to know what is the mistake in partitioning that I have done so as to correct it and reinstall Ubuntu and windows without problems.

Comment: Judging from the partition layout, there really doesn't appear be anything necessarily preventing both OSes from working. You mentioned you had to enable UEFI at some point, maybe that is causing these issues? AFAIK UEFI dual boots are a little more complicated, is there no way to use BIOS? If you install Windows first, does the install work? If you then install Ubuntu, can you start Ubuntu? In that case it's probably just grub that's confused. And you should run a SMART test to rule out a failing hard drive in either case.